# please explain this java script code for me

Tags: javascript

this code takes a string in input only containing characters A,T,G and C and replace the A with T and G to C and vice versa but I don't know how it is working please exaplain to me line by line. Thank You.

```
function DNAStrand(dna) {
  return dna.replace(/./g, function(c) {
    return DNAStrand.pairs[c]
  })
}

DNAStrand.pairs = {
  A: 'T',
  T: 'A',
  C: 'G',
  G: 'C',
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: `/./` is a regex that matches any character, so this code replaces any character with the value next to it in `DNAStrand.pairs`

Answer (score 0):

For example, you are calling function `DNAStrand('AG')`

- 'AG' will be replaced if matched with regEx `/./g`
- A is matched then we are going to search its value in the `DNAStrand.pairs` list as below:
  `DNAStrand.pairs['A']` --> return `T`
- Consecutively, G is match then look into `DNAStrand.pairs['G']` list --> return `C`